# Does UI Spy produce a log file?

Tags: ui-automation, logfiles, ui-spy

I had UI Spy (UISpy.exe) crash. I closed the program and didn't even look at the stack trace in the error message. Does UI Spy produce a log? Is there a way to retrieve this previous failure if there is not a log file? I checked the system event viewer, and did not see any errors there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've looked in all the usual locations. If you missed the stack trace, I'd say you're not finding out. Considering that UI Spy is way out of date, I recommend using a newer product. [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) and [UIA Verify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/) were both updated this year.

Comment: I'm being asked to use UISpy to verify a defect with a UI automation suite (Ranorex).  Thanks for the recommendation of the more up to date tools.

Comment: UIA Verify is functionally equivalent (in my experience) and should be able to report all the same details.

Comment: Plus, how out of date is Ranorex if they're recommending UI Spy?!